# C++ 11 thread and pointer parameter

Tags: c++, multithreading, pointers, c++11

I want to print strings with contents 1,2,3,4,5 using 5 threads, My working environment:

OS version : CentOS Linux release 7.0.1406 (Core)

g++ version: g++ (GCC) 4.8.2 20140120 (Red Hat 4.8.2-16)

compile cmd: g++ -o thread_sz -std=c++11 -pthread thread_sz.cpp

```
// file name: thread_sz.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <thread>

#include <unistd.h>

using namespace std;

void myFunc1(char* sz)
{
    printf("sz = %s\n", sz);
}

void myFunc2(const char* const sz)
{
    printf("const char* const sz = %s\n", sz);
}

void myFunc3(string str)
{
    printf("string str = %s\n", str.c_str());
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    for(int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        char sz[16];
        sprintf(sz, "%2d", i);
        const string str(sz);

        std::thread t1(myFunc1, sz);
        std::thread t2(myFunc2, (const char* const)str.c_str());
        std::thread t3(myFunc3, str);

        t1.detach();
        t2.detach();
        t3.detach();
    }
    usleep(1000000); // sleep 1 second
    return 0;
}
```

Output something like:

```
const char* const sz =  1
sz =  3
const char* const sz =  2
string str =  3
sz =  4
sz =  4
string str =  2
sz =  5
const char* const sz =  4
sz =  5
string str =  1
const char* const sz =  5
string str =  4
string str =  5
const char* const sz =  5
```

I run the program for lots of times, and the result seems:

```
string str output: 100% correct
sz output: ~10% correct
const char* const sz output: ~50% correct
```

My questions are:

1, Why MyFunc1 and MyFunc2 are not 100% correct, what's the differences btw them. How to fix it.

2, Can MyFunc3 work 100% correctly.

3, If I comment out this line
`usleep(1000000); // sleep 1 second`
MyFunc1 may output empty value like
`sz =`, Why?

Thank you very much.

Comment: You are overwriting sz before the threads have time to read it.

Comment: Both `sz` and `str` are automatic vars that exit scope before the next iteration of your loop. Accessing *either* from `t1` and `t2`invokes undefined behavior once they are destroyed. Thus your program is ill-formed. `t3` works because you're sending the thread a copy of `str`.

Comment: @Baldrick, how to fix it, if MyFunc1 is API from 3rd party.

Comment: FYI `std::this_thead::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));`

Comment: @WhozCraig is correct, the 2 taking pointers are copying the pointers (not the contents) and when the local variable (`sz` inside the for-loop) goes out of scope then you're left with *undefined behavior*.

Comment: @JamesAdkison the same is true for the `c_str()` pointer taken from `str`. When the loop reaches the closing `}` `str` is destroyed. `t3` works because a copy is sent to the thread. If `t3`'s parameter were a reference and `std::ref(str)` were passed it would be just as bad as the other two. Worse, moving them out of the loop scope belays that UB, but retains the race condition Baldrick mentioned.

Comment: @FengYANG pass your MyFunc1 a heap allocated char array using the `new` operator, as long as you know you'll be able to `delete[]` it later. Another option is `join` your threads before the next loop.

Comment: @WhozCraig Yes, I agree (that's why I said the *2* taking pointers (i.e, the 2 functions to which you're referring). Fend, we'd have to know more about the behavior of that 3rd party API. If it takes ownership of the given pointer then you can just allocate each on the heap. Otherwise, you need to keep them alive (and not alter the existing pointers) until the threads complete there execution.

Comment: @JamesAdkison 3rd party API may exit after several seconds or minutes later, because its a login API, I have thousands or more user account needs to login on my server, if I join the thread, the application may startup using hours or more. ^o^

Comment: So write a wrapper that calls their API, but owns the resources, and use that wrapper as the thread-proc. Once their API is finished you wrapper can clean-up before finishing the thread. Who said you had to pass *their* API function directly to `std::thread`? you can pass a wrapper that *you* write, and call theirs from *that*. But I *strongly* recc joining if at all possible.

Comment: @WhozCraig thank you very much, wrapper it great, I've written my own one and it works great.

Comment: @WhozCraig It's not ill-formed, but "just" UB. Ill-formed would require a diagnostic from the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

In each cycle of loop you creates variables (character array and string object) and you pass it to myFuncX running in new, independent threads. It can often happen that the loop in main thread steps to the next cycle but one of the threads started in that cycle and runs myFuncX did not finish its running.

The differences between the behavior of function depends on the type of argument. myFunc1 waits for char* input, so a pointer to a character (array). The main loop creates a new character array in each cycle and pass its pointer to myFunc1. But this array is a local variable, so its content is only valid in that cycle. If the main loop steps to next cycle the content of previously passed argument to myFunc1 is indefinite because it points to a memory location where the destroyed local variable **was**. This is the reason why sometimes or often the method writes bad values.

The same thing happens in case of myFunc2. The difference is that myFunc2 waits for a const char* pointer which points to the string object's character array, but this string object is also a local variable, so it is destroyed also at the end of each cycle.

But, in case of myFunc3 the methods waits for string object **not** a pointer. When you pass it to myFunc3 a new object will be created in the method which content is the same as the string created in main loop. **But this object is a different object, only its content is the same.** Therefore it is all the same what happens the string created in main loop, the myFunc3 uses its own local string object therefore the printing will be perfect.

Answer (score 0):

My answers are:

1. MyFunc1 and MyFunc2 are correct, you just probably don't know what they are really doing. What they are really doing is to read memory under a given pointer at the time when there was a scheduled time to execute them - and they just read whatever is there at that time. No one has guaranteed you that `sprintf()` from the next iteration of the `for` loop will happen before the context switch to execute the thread from the current iteration, which runs this function.

   1.1. The MyFunc2 theoretically uses a string, however it uses the physical string variable that is exactly the same way overwritten at the next time. In this particular case you have more luck than reason because most likely the string is being destroyed at the end of loop and a new string is created at the next iteration, which involves deallocation of the memory and reallocating it again, at least in theory - you are just lucky that this newly created string is getting exactly the same pointer to a newly allocated memory for the string as it had before. Practically you are passing a dangling pointer, which by a good luck has the same value as the newly allocated array (that happens always when you use `str.c_str()` and do anything else than immediate copy or processing in place of the returned character array).
2. MyFunc3 doesn't work correctly either, you just have again more luck than reason. It shows the correct number because it holds its copy in `std::string` type variable - so, in contrast to 1 and 2, reading from `sz` happens at the thread construction time rather than at the time when the threaded function is executing. Effectively, your function does not refer to any variables other than its own. But there is still no guarantee that the function scheduled for the previous iteration will finish its job before that function is scheduled for the next iteration. You probably won't observe it in your case, but there is a theoretical possibility that MyFunc3 could print values not in the order of iteration (it's enough that, for example, the thread from previous iteration has been assigned to another system lightweight-thread than that from the next iteration, and that from previous iteration has been by some reason slightly delayed - and you may have a case that, for example, 4 is printed before 3).
3. If you don't put the program into sleep, then probably your function is fired when the stack of `main()` function has been already released and possibly overwritten by something. May happen that in your case these are zeros. In a really bad luck you'll have a long string of random binary data, until the program reaches the address that is not assigned to program's segments.

   3.1. Putting the program into sleep only delays problems in time, not solves them.

I'd suggest you read about `thread::join()` or even generally about writing threaded applications.